# Error while using react-router in multi step registration form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I get an error when i implement react router in my working multiple step registration form. When i click personal info link i get an error on console saying

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerName' of undefined"
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null".
```

Similiary when i click on Location i get same sort of errors, instead of ownerName i get error on `"'city' of undefined"`. What might be the cause?

**UPDATE:** "react": "^0.14.7" and "react-router": "^2.0.0"

**My Code**

**Index.js(entry point)**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {render} from 'react-dom'; 
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import assign from 'object-assign';

import Layout from './components/Layout';

let fieldValues = {
  ownerName:'',
  email:'',
  phoneNumber:'',
  city     : '',
  place    : ''
}


class AddRent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
            step: 1
        };
    }

  saveValues(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = Object.assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }()
    console.log('fieldValues are', fieldValues);
  }


  nextStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step+1;
    this.setState({step:newStep});
  }

  previousStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step-1
    this.setState({
      step : newStep
    });
  }


  showStep() {
  switch (this.state.step) {
    case 1:
      return <RenderPersonalInfo fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues.bind(this)} />
    case 2:
      return <RenderLocation fieldValues={fieldValues}
                           nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                           previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)}
                           saveValues={this.saveValues.bind(this)} />
  }
}

  render() {
    var style = {
      width : (this.state.step / 2 * 100) + '%',
      backgroundColor:'#000'
    }

    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress" style={style}></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

class RenderPersonalInfo extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
            <div>
              <h3>Personal Information</h3>
              <p className="subtitle">Provide your authentic information so rent seekers can contact you</p>
              <hr/>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor='name'>Owner Name</label>
                <input ref="name" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.ownerName} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Owner name" />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input ref="email" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.email} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input ref="phone" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.phoneNumber} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone number" />
              </div>
              <hr/>
                <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works" ref="personalInfo" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
      );
  }
  nextStep(step){
     var data = {
          ownerName  : this.refs.name.value,
          email : this.refs.email.value,
          phoneNumber: this.refs.phone.value,
        }
        console.log(data.ownerName);
        if ((data.ownerName)&&(data.email)&&(data.phoneNumber)) {
          this.props.saveValues(data);
          this.props.nextStep();
        }
        else{
          alert('please enter the name, email and phone number');
        }
  }
}



class RenderLocation extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>Help guests find your place</h3>
                <p className="subtitle">will use this information to find a place that’s in the right spot.</p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                    <input ref="city" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.city} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Biratnagar" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <label htmlFor="placeName">Name of Place</label>
                    <input ref="place" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.place} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="placeName" placeholder="Ganesh Chowk" />
                </div><hr/>
                <div className="row continueBtn">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep.bind(this)}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-right" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }

     nextStep(step){
        var data = {
          city  :this.refs.city.value,
          place :this.refs.place.value,
        }
        if ((data.city)&&(data.place)) {
          this.props.saveValues(data);
          this.props.nextStep();
        }
        else{
          alert('please enter the name of city and place');
        }

    }

}

render(
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <Route path="personal" component={RenderPersonalInfo}></Route>
                <Route path="location" component={RenderLocation}></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>,document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <h1>I am Layout</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <ul className="list-group">
              <li className="list-group"><Link to="personal">Personal Info</Link></li>
              <li className="list-group"><Link to="location">Location</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-8">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading `this.props.fieldValues.city` and a few other values from `this.props` in `RenderLocation` that you never specified. The `render()` method crashes because `this.props.fieldValues` is `undefined`, and you get cryptic errors as the result.

**Always look at the first errors (thrown by your code).**

The subsequent errors like

- `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerName' of undefined"`
- `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null".`

are just symptoms of React getting confused **after** your code throws an earlier exception.

The `AddRent` component that used to specify these props is not used anywhere in your code. Since router uses the router configuration to create your components, it won’t give them any custom props—you need to read `this.props.params` supplied by the router and figure out the current `step`, as well as related `fieldValues`, from them.

Comment: Are there any good ways to get them spout the errors properly?

Comment: To get *who* to spout the errors properly? React will ship support for “error boundaries” soon which will allow surfacing the right errors nicely in the UI as you develop the app. For now, just scroll console to the top and check the earliest error.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I meant React to spout the errors properly. At the time I wrote the comment, I was wondering why the errors were being swallowed. It was due to promises in my case.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, if you use Promises, you totally want to make sure that whatever implementation you are using reports unhandled rejections.